# Customize windows hotkeys

Tags: windows, powershell, hotkeys

My question is about a way to speed-up everyday writing. I'm often required to repeat certain text-snippets in different forms. One way is to use:

> Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V

but I want to keep the Ctrl-C for temporary text-snippets and be able to create a custom hotkey where I predefine the text that I can paste, e.g. if I press Ctrl-T, while having the mouse in the url-entry in a browser, a string like "hi, I hope you are well!" will be pasted. I have been looking into using the windows powershell, but I'm not experienced enough to do this...
Thx for any help (be gentle, this is my first question!) and thx for all the help throughout the years :)

Comment: This is not something that Powershell would probably be the best tool for in my opinion. I would suggest Auto Hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh it seems @EBGreen's idea did provide a good answer! Thanks :) Here is what I found:

`^j::
Send, name.surname@company.com
return`

binds Ctrl+j to the string "name.surname@company.com", when using the autohotkey-language.

Check out https://autohotkey.com/ for more details!